# Failed to cast variant value "sample text" to FIXED in Snowflake External table data load

Tags: casting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on loading data from AWS S3 location to Snowflake External table. During the loading process I am getting an error is "Failed to cast variant value "Text Data" to FIXED". Can any one please help me on this.

File format is :

```
create or replace file format my_csv_format
type = csv field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1
null_if = ('NULL','null')
empty_field_as_null = true FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' encoding = 'UTF-8' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE ;
```

External Table :

```
create or replace external table "AAW"."ACS_CLS_MART"."EXT_RPT_MASTER"
                    (
                     Conc                                VARCHAR as (VALUE:c1::VARCHAR),
                     ID                                  VARCHAR as (VALUE:c2::VARCHAR),
                     Customer_Name                       VARCHAR as (VALUE:c20::VARCHAR)
                     ) 
                     with location = @aws_s3_to_snf 
                     file_format = my_csv_format
                     auto_refresh = true;
```

Comment: What kind of files do you have in the S3 location?

Comment: Can you also update your question with some sample records from your file, including the record that contains the "Text data" value? Thanks

Comment: Hi Sergiu and NickW, in my S3 Bucket location CSV file is stored data is "BREAKHRU BEVERGGE GROUP LLC".

Comment: Customer Customer_Name
320889 BREAKHRU BEVERGGE GROUP LLC
320889 BREAKHRU BEVERGGE GROUP LLC
320889 BREAKHRU BEVERGGE GROUP LLC
320889 BREAKHRU BEVERGGE GROUP LLC

Comment: Please don’t add additional information in comments, update your question and format the text appropriately. Also, the data you put in your comment has no commas in it so it doesn’t appear to be in a csv format

Comment: Can I add my CSV file ?

Comment: Just paste a few relevant rows into your question

Comment: "BREAKTHRU BEVERAGE GROUP LLC"  --- this is the row I am facing issue whenever load data from AWS s3 to Snowflake External table.

Comment: Could any one please help me on this ?